# Using javax.smartcardio package on Android?

Tags: android, smartcard, javacard, pcsc, smartcardio

I have made an application in Java using Eclipse as a library for reading and writing to a Java Card applet. So far we're using ACS ACR38 reader. But now we need to port this library to Android. What can I use to replace the `javax.smartcardio` package in the original project? Preferably something similar since I'd prefer to minimize re-implementing as much as possible.

Note that I'm going to use a custom reader with OTG cable for the Android version (not an ACS reader). It is an FTDI device. I've looked into [SCDroid](http://www.scdroid.com/product/software) and [Seek for Android](https://github.com/seek-for-android) but those don't seem to be what I need (the test application from SCdroid does not detect my device), and I'm not sure if the SCDroid one is free?

For now I'm only using [UsbSerial](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) library to only receive and send APDUs but I'm wondering if there's any similar library for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ACS Android sdk : https://android.acs.com.hk/

Your reader ACR38 is supported on Android

Comment: I'm not going to use the ACR38 reader for the android version, but a custom card reader using an FTDI device, would it still work?

Comment: Do you have specific SDK (android or java or c) with this smartcard reader ?

Comment: The reader is solely made for the purpose of running my program (but in android), I'm not quite sure what specs should the reader have and what library I can use then. If I can make it work somehow with existing smartcard library I'd gladly tell the hardware guy to stick to a standard (only thing I know the guy said it's not CCID compliant yet, should it?). But first I need to know which library I can use.